# Convert rows to columns for the CALENDAR_DATE with respect to Month Name and Year

Tags: sql-server

I am new to SQL Server and I am facing this trouble please need your help on this.
I am using SQL Server 2008

I have two tables

table 1: `CALENDAR_DIMENSION`

```
Row_Seq(numeric(5,0), null)
CALENDAR_YEAR(int, null)
CALENDAR_MONTH_NO(int, null)
CALENDAR_MONTH_NAME(varchar(15), null)
CALENDAR_DATE(date, null)
```

table 2: `HOLIDAY_DETAILS`

```
CALENDAR_DATE(date, not null)
DESCRIPTION (varchar(50), null)
CALENDAR_DAY_NAME(varchar(15), null)
IS_WORKING_DAY(int, null)
```

My requirement is to get the data from the two tables as below for the `CALENDAR_DATE` it should pick the values from `HOLIDAY_DETAILS` table from the columnn `IS_WORKING_DAY` (0= Holiday, 1= working day)

Calendar_Year   Calendar_Month_No   Calendar_Date
2014            1       01-01-2014  02-01-2014  03-01-2014  04-01-2014  05-01-2014  ……. 31-01-2014
2014            2       01-02-2014  02-02-2014  03-02-2013  03-02-2013  04-02-2013  ……. 28-02-2014
2014            3       01-03-2014  02-03-2014  03-03-2014  04-03-2014  05-03-2014  ……. 31-03-2014

Result  should be in this manner after Joining to CALENDAR_DIMENSION. First I need all the CALENDAR-YEAR, CALENDAR_MONTH and CALENDAR_DAYS in horizontal ways as shown in the example below from HOLIDAY_DETAILS table and then would like to join to table CALENDAR_DIMENSION to get the IS_WORKING_DAY status on the Days.
Calendar_Year   Calendar_Month_No   Calendar_Date
2014            1       1   1   1   0   0   ……. 1
            2       0   0   1   0   0   ……. 1
            3       0   0   1   0   0   ……. 1

```
Working Day = 1                         
Holiday = 0
```

Comment: Could you improve the display of your lines? It is not readable

Comment: Create [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) test and sure more people will help you...

Answer (score 0):

according to me YEAR_MONTH-DAY is useless.i will not create this table .you can verify my script with your requirement and tell how it won't work.after verification you can easily join with holiday table.

```
Declare @year varchar(4)=2014

;with cte as
(
select @year calyear,1 monthno,cast(@year+'-'+'1'+'-'+'1' as date) as date1,cast(@year+'-'+'1'+'-'+'2' as date) date2,cast(@year+'-'+'1'+'-'+'3' as date) date3,cast(@year+'-'+'1'+'-'+'4' as date) date4,cast(@year+'-'+'1'+'-'+'5' as date) date5,cast(@year+'-'+'1'+'-'+'6' as date) date6,cast(@year+'-'+'1'+'-'+'7' as date) date7
union all
select calyear,monthno+1,dateadd(month,1, date1),dateadd(month,1, date2),dateadd(month,1, date3),dateadd(month,1, date4),dateadd(month,1, date5),dateadd(month,1, date6),dateadd(month,1, date7) from cte where calyear=2014 and monthno<=11

)
select * from cte
```

Comment: Hi KumarHarsh, Thanks for answering my query. I appreciate your quick response. How to implement the same AA_Holiday_Details table when I am trying to do I'm getting errors. AA_Holiday_Details has only CALENDAR_DATE. I would like to Join both the tables and get the result as follow:  Note:- I have added the image pls find the image. Need your help on this. I need Calendar_Day_Name, IS_working_Day, Horizontally under each day to show the status.Description, Thanks in advance

Comment: i do not see any image attached.i already told you that first verify my query then think of joining holiday table.See joining is not a problem.problem is how to display.you are already display all day of month horizontally.so each row each month,so if there is more than one holiday in a month then how you want them to appear.you mean pivot holiday table also horizontally ?show your output desire very clearly .

Comment: Hi Harsh I'm unable to upload image as it is say I need 10 reputations. I have updated my query above pls go thru it and help me. From Holiday_Details first I need YEAR, Month_NO and Days in Horizontal after that I want to join this result query to CALENDAR_DIM table with CALENDAR_DATE which is available in both the tables. And after joining I would like to use IS_WORKING_DAY column  from CALENDAR_DIM table to update the DAYS from the HOLIDAY_DETAILS Query to make those results to 0 = Holiday and 1 = working day. If you can share me your email I will mail the image. Thanks in advance.